# How to properly plot the slope of a BB line?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like to determine and plot the slope of the upper BB1 (close, 20) line, in degrees.

It seems to me the the plot isn't showing the degree of the line, is instead showing the *speed of change* in the slope.

What do I do wrong?

[image]

The code is this:

```
//@version=5

indicator ("BB slope", overlay = false)
dX = input.int     (title="dX", defval=2, display=display.all - display.status_line)

BBdev = ta.stdev (close, 20)
BBupper = ta.sma (close, 20) + BBdev
BBlower = ta.sma (close, 20) - BBdev

upperslope = math.todegrees(math.atan((BBupper[0]-BBupper[dX])/(dX+1)))

plot(upperslope, title = "BB upper", color = color.blue, linewidth = 2)
hline(0, title = "Midline", color=color.black)
```

Comment: What makes you sure that its the speed of change in the slope (aka the second derivative)?

Comment: Nothing, it just look like it, im not sure

Comment: Well you're taking the arctangent of the slope of two bollinger bands. Seems a bit unreasonable to think you could look at its value and determine whats going on. Do you at least have a reason why you think the value is not what you are trying to calculate? Did you copy-paste this code, or did you not mean to take the arctangent of the slope?

Comment: Sorry, i shouldnt include the line with the BBlower variable, as the program doesnt use it yet only the BBupper one. If you look the parts, where the band is rising constantly in around 45 degrees, i should see on the indicator an aprox flat line around the value 45. Instead i see a big peak, wich then returns to zero even if the band is still rising (so this means it showing the change of the slope and not the actual slope)

Comment: Its my code, but about the arctangent question: for my desired result i had to use this function. Or is this a mathematical mistake?